# loop control with digital_ocean ansible module

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean

Thanks to other stackoverflow users, I have managed to pull some data out of a variable registered by the `digital_ocean` ansible module. I attempted to use `loop_control` to print only part of the huge variable that is registered. Here is an extract from the role:

```
- name: Add droplet
  digital_ocean: >
{ some parameters }
  with_dict: "{{ droplets_up }}"
  register: my_droplet

- debug: msg="Droplet IP is {{ item.droplet.ip_address }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_droplet.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item }}"
```

I'm obviously doing it wrong here, as it prints the whole variable as well as the debug message. I don't quite understand loop_control at this point, but does anyone know if it's possible to use it in this manner with this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debug` action has `result['_ansible_verbose_always'] = True`, so it will always print full item, no matter what your `label` is (although `label: "{{item}}"` doesn't change anything, try `label: "{{ item.droplet.ip_address }}"`).

If you just need to list all your IP addresses, use `map` filter and single debug statement:

```
- name: Print droplets IP
  debug:
    msg: "{{ my_droplet.results | map(attribute='droplet.ip_address') | list }}"
```